# Subaru "seized" question

Tags: subaru, forester

Let me preface this by saying I know next to nothing about cars, so excuse me if this doesn't make sense. . .

I have a 2003 Subaru Forester that needs a ball bearing replaced (I believe that's what it's called?!). When they went to fix this yesterday, apparently they couldn't do so because everything was "seized up." They tried calling around for a price quote for the cost of fixing this issue, but we're unable to do so, I'm guessing because it was a Saturday.

I will call back tomorrow to get more information. Google searches only bring up results about a seized engine, which I don't believe is the issue because the car is currently drivable.

Also, what is the urgency of getting something like this fixed, from a scale of the car will eventually stop working to the car may spontaneously explode?

I apologize if I haven't provided enough info to answer the question. The mechanic that worked on my car wasn't around when I went in, and the other employees didn't really seem to know what was going on. And me being car illiterate didn't even know what questions to ask.

Thanks!!

Comment: Where is this seized bearing? Engine belt tensioner? A/C ? Top suspension? Until you can tell us exactly which component...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! There is a slight issue with your question, that being, you are asking for pricing on getting something fixed, which is off-topic for the site. The reason for this is because of locality and because prices change, this will become obsolete very quickly. I'm going to edit this part of the question out. Also, I think we really do need a bit more information, because a "seized bearing" could mean a lot of things. Maybe if you described what you took the car in for in the first place, it would help us to help you.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I was afraid I was missing some vital information. I don't know what exactly is seized, just that it made it impossible to fix the bearing. I took it in originally for some other repairs (tires and a cracked belt) and they found this bearing problem during an inspection. I wasn't having any issues driving it. It runs fine from what I can tell. I guess I'm wondering if repairs are even worth pursuing given that the car is only worth between two and three thousand right now.

Comment: It really depends on what exactly the problem is and then what your pocket book can afford.